# How to update a json array using the key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Let's say I have this json in my jsonb column

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "firstName",
      "age": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "lastName",
      "age": 25
    },
    ...
}
```

How can I update the "firstName" only without using the index?

I have this so far, but this is using the index which I don't want to use

```
UPDATE person
SET 
    field = jsonb_set(field, 
    concat('{fields, 0, name'}')::text[], 
    'new value'::jsonb, 
    TRUE)
```

Comment: Show table structure ?

Comment: *"I have this so far, but this is using the index which I don't want to use"* But you can try `SET enable_seqscan = ON; SET enable_indexscan = OFF; SET enable_indexonlyscan  = OFF; ... `  as mentioned in the manual [Planner Method Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to unnest the array elements, replace the one you want and then aggregate them back:

```sql
update the_table tg
   set data = data||(select jsonb_build_object(
                                 'fields', jsonb_agg(case
                                                       when t.j ->> 'name' = 'firstName' 
                                                         then t.j||'{"name": "new_name"}'
                                                       else t.j
                                                     end))
                     from jsonb_array_elements(tg.data -> 'fields') as t(j))
where ....;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/BZVKD68215